# Selecting an element in an Associative Array in a different way in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Ok I have this kind of associative array in PHP

```
$arr = array(
    "fruit_aac" => "apple",
    "fruit_2de" => "banana",
    "fruit_ade" => "grapes",
    "other_add" => "sugar",
    "other_nut" => "coconut",
);
```

now what I want is to select only the elements that starts with key `fruit_`. How can be this possible? can I use a regex? or any PHP array functions available? Is there any workaround? Please give some examples for your solutions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$fruits = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'fruit_') === 0) {
        $fruits[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: haha worked like a charm! anyways thank you for giving me an idea how to use the `===` thank you

Answer (score 3):

One solution is as follows:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
     if(strpos($key, "fruit_") === 0) {
         ...
         ...
     }
}
```

The === ensures that the string was found at position 0, since strpos can also return FALSE if string was not found.

Answer (score 3):

You try it:

```
function filter($var) {

    return strpos($var, 'fruit_') !== false;

}

$arr = array(
    "fruit_aac"=>"apple",
    "fruit_2de"=>"banana",
    "fruit_ade"=>"grapes",
    "other_add"=>"sugar",
    "other_nut"=>"coconut",
);

print_r(array_flip(array_filter(array_flip($arr), 'filter')));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to try regular expression then you can try code given below...

```
$arr = array("fruit_aac"=>"apple",
    "fruit_2de"=>"banana",
    "fruit_ade"=>"grapes",
    "other_add"=>"sugar",
    "other_nut"=>"coconut",
);

$arr2 = array();

foreach($arr AS $index=>$array){
if(preg_match("/^fruit_.*/", $index)){
        $arr2[$index] = $array;
}
}

print_r($arr2);
```

I hope it will be helpful for you.

thanks